# C++ eigen3 linear algebra library, odd performance results

Tags: c++, performance, gcc, vectorization, eigen

I've been using eigen3 linear algebra library in c++ for a while, and I've always tried to take advantage of the vectorization performance benefits. Today, I've decided to test how much vectorization really speeds my programs up. So, I've written the following test program:

--- eigentest.cpp ---

```
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>
using namespace Eigen;

#include <iostream>

int main() {
        Matrix4d accumulator=Matrix4d::Zero();
        Matrix4d randMat = Matrix4d::Random();
        Matrix4d constMat = Matrix4d::Constant(2);
        for(int i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
                randMat+=constMat;
                accumulator+=randMat*randMat;
        }
        std::cout<<accumulator(0,0)<<"\n"; // To avoid optimizing everything away
        return 0;
}
```

Then I've run this program after compiling it with different compiler options: (The results aren't one-time, many runs give similar results)

```
$ g++ eigentest.cpp  -o eigentest -DNDEBUG -std=c++0x -march=native
$ time ./eigentest
5.33334e+18

real    0m4.409s
user    0m4.404s
sys 0m0.000s
$ g++ eigentest.cpp  -o eigentest -DNDEBUG -std=c++0x
$ time ./eigentest 
5.33334e+18

real    0m4.085s
user    0m4.040s
sys 0m0.000s
$ g++ eigentest.cpp  -o eigentest -DNDEBUG -std=c++0x -march=native -O3
$ time ./eigentest 
5.33334e+18

real    0m0.147s
user    0m0.136s
sys 0m0.000s
$ g++ eigentest.cpp  -o eigentest -DNDEBUG -std=c++0x -O3
$time ./eigentest
5.33334e+18

real    0m0.025s
user    0m0.024s
sys 0m0.000s
```

And here's my relevant cpu information:

```
model name  : AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 5600+
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt rdtscp lm 3dnowext 3dnow extd_apicid pni cx16 lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy 3dn
```

I know that there's no vectorization going on when I don't use the compiler option `-march=native` because when I don't use it, I never get a segmentation fault, or wrong result due to vectorization, as opposed to the case that I use it (with `-NDEBUG`).

These results lead me to believe that, at least on my CPU vectorization with eigen3 results in slower execution. Who should I blame? My CPU, eigen3 or gcc?

Edit: To remove any doubts, I've now tried to add the `-DEIGEN_DONT_ALIGN` compiler option in cases where I'm trying to measure the performance of the no-vectorization case, and the results are the same. Furthermore, when I add `-DEIGEN_DONT_ALIGN` along with `-march=native` the results become very close to the case without `-march=native`.

Comment: which g++ version are you using?

Comment: On my platform (Intel Q9550) I get identical speeds whether or not I use march=native. -O3 however results in aggressive inlining, use of SSE and unrolling. Adding -mss3 results in slightly different assembly with exactly the same run time performance. I don't really get your point with the segfault, do you have a set of compiler flags that makes your program crash?

Comment: @KillianDS my gcc version: `gcc --version`:
`gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) 4.5.2`

Comment: @Bob I've tried deliberately setting up a vectorization problem by defining a class with a `char` member before a `Vector2d` member, without `EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW` then creating an object with new and compiled with `-NDEBUG` to bypass the assert. Without `-march=native` I get the right results from the calculations and with it, I get a segmentation fault. That tells me that vectorization is not used without -march.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that the compiler is smarter than you think and still optimizes a lot of stuff away.

On my platform, I get about 9ms without `-march=native` and about 39ms with `-march=native`. However, if I replace the line above the return by

```
std::cout<<accumulator<<"\n";
```

then the timings change to 78ms without `-march=native` and about 39ms with `-march=native`.

Thus, it seems that without vectorization, the compiler realizes that you only use the (0,0) element of the matrix and so it only computes that element. However, it can't do that optimization if vectorization is enabled.

If you output the whole matrix, thus forcing the compiler to compute all the entries, then vectorization speeds up the program with a factor 2, as expected (though I'm surprised to see that it is exactly a factor 2 in my timings).

Comment: Nice catch! The compiler is indeed smarter than I think. FYI, I've run the same test, I get 42ms vs. 112ms on my `Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU M 350  @ 2.27GHz`, tomorrow I'll try the same with that CPU mentioned in the question and see how it goes there.